# Webcam.js Error: No supported webcam interface found error on server but not in localhost

Tags: webcam.js

I'm loading the exactly same page  from localhost or from an Apache server.
If loaded from localhost it works fine display video from camera and I can take a snapshot
When loaded from apache I got error message

> Webcam.js Error: No supported webcam interface found

**these are test I have done**

A.php built-in server

http://localhost:8080/webcam.html

1.browser Chromium  79.0.3945.130
  result : success
2.browser : Firefox 72.0.2
result:success

B.Apache on linux server virtual host
http://example.com/webcam.html

1.browser Chromium  79.0.3945.130
  result:Webcam.js Error: No supported webcam interface found
2.browser : Firefox 72.0.2
result:Webcam.js Error: No supported webcam interface found

what I could expect is a permission error
not interface not found
Any help is appreciate
Thanks

Comment: It's a security issue, make sure that your are serving your site trough `hhtps` https://github.com/jhuckaby/webcamjs/issues/124

Comment: Thanks I found a workaround for Chrome
Add the domain in whitelist in setting 
unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure